# Can't use "download" as a function name in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've had a problem with this little snippet:

```
<script>
function download() {
    alert('Hi');
}
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:download();">Test</a>
```

Once I click on the link in Chrome 14.0, I get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

in Firefox and IE it works just fine. I solved the problem by renaming the function but I'm still curious what's with the "download" thing in Chrome. It's not a reserved keyword as far as I know so what might it be?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Confirmed. Even removing the `javascript:` that shouldn't be there doesn't help. Weird!

Comment: Don't use global functions. Place your functions in a namespace and bind the event handler programmatically.

Comment: @Muu, I have plenty but even if I start an incognito window (which apparently disables extensions) I still get the error. Also, as Tomalak pointed below, console.log(download) gives undefined.

Comment: @Amati: Where are you doing this? If you created a jsFiddle, note that the actual code is run in an iframe and global variables are not accessible from the console.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<a>` elements have a `download` attribute in HTML5 as explained [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download), with a default value of `""` (an empty string).

This means that `download === this.download` in the `onclick` handler (`this` is the element in `onevent` attributes), and therefore the `download` attribute of the element is superior to the `download` property of `window`.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/2ecpn/) lists all string attributes that are present by default. You can see `download` is an attribute just like `innerHTML`, which [also fails](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/2ecpn/1/) with the exact same reason when used as a function (i.e. trying to refer to `window.innerHTML`, but instead executing `elem.innerHTML()`).

As said in the comments, using `window` makes for no confusion as to what property/attribute variables will evaluate to.

---

This scope behaviour does actually not seem to due to the `this` value but rather a specific "scope chain" that is being constructed.

As per [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes):

> Lexical Environment Scope
>
> Let `Scope` be the result of `NewObjectEnvironment(the element's Document, the global environment)`.
>
> If the element has a form owner, let `Scope` be the result of `NewObjectEnvironment(the element's form owner, Scope)`.
>
> Let `Scope` be the result of `NewObjectEnvironment(the element's object, Scope)`.

I.e. what is happening is the scope chain is `window` -> `document` -> `element` (increasing superiority). This means that `download` evaluates to `element.download` and not `window.download`. What also can be concluded from this is that `getElementById` will bubble up to `document.getElementById` (given `elem.getElementById` does not exist).

I set up [a systematic example](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/X5syU/3/) so that you can see how variables bubble up the scope chain:

```
window.a   = 1;
document.a = 2;
elem.a     = 3;

window.b   = 4;
document.b = 5;

window.c   = 6;
```

Then, `<a ... onclick="console.log(a, b, c)">` logs `3`, `5`, `6` when clicked.

Comment: I don't like this weird scope aggregation thing, or whatever you want to call it... the same with forms. +1

Comment: So does that suggest that this could be fixed by changing it to `onClick="window.download()"`?

Comment: @Joe White: Yes, `window` is always the same thing everywhere on the page. `this` isn't, what is causing the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I knew jQuery bound `this` to the element, but I never knew that browser events also did this by default. Unexpected to those of us who have used Delphi/WinForms/WPF/Silverlight, where all the event handlers are methods of the window so `this` is always the window.

Comment: @Joe: `this` is not the problem here. That `this` refers to the element should be known... the problem is that the *scope* of the event handler does not only contain the global scope, but also the element itself as scope. It is as if someone did: `with(theElement) { theElement.onclick = function() {...} }`... that is the confusing part.

Comment: N.B: And until now I have not found anything that specifies this behaviour.... any references are welcome :)

Comment: @FelixKling: [Here's a reference.](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm#jscript4-CHP-19-SECT-1.6) *"Event handlers defined as HTML attributes have a more complex scope chain. The head of the scope chain is the call object... The next object in an event handler's scope chain isn't the global object, however; it is the object that triggered the event handler."*

Comment: Thanks pimvdb! Makes sense now. Apparently other browsers haven't implemented the 'download' attribute yet. If I try renaming the function to a widely supported attribute, all browsers show error.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ: Thanks (I think I even read this already but forgot it ;)), but is there also a standard describing this? *Edit:* Nevermind, further down it says it was never standardized.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Here is another: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes. "The user agent must set the thisArg (...) to the event handler's object.". It's the HTML5 specification.

Comment: @primvdb: What you referring to is again what `this` will refer to (to the element), but it does not explain how the scope chain is created.

Comment: @pimvdb: Hmmm... That seems to deal with setting the calling context rather than defining the scope chain. EDIT: Felix was quicka. :)

Comment: @Felix Kling & @Ӫ_._Ӫ: Sorry, this seems closer: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes. "Let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(the element's object, Scope)." So that would mean that the element itself is pushed before any other scopes (e.g. the window). This also makes sense since `document.xxx` functions seem available without using `document` inside a handler attribute as well (`document` is also pushed into the scope chain as per the rules there): http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/X5syU/1/

Comment: @pimvdb: Yes, good find (bookmarked) :) So they finally decided to put this in specification. But I still think that this is a very confusing feature. Having DOM elements in the scope chain just feels wrong somehow... at least for now ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: Don't mind it, you don't define events in HTML anyway do you? :)

Comment: True... but that makes the different ways of attaching event handlers even more inconsistent... imo there should not be much of a difference between adding an event handler inline or via the DOM property... anyways, that's not a topic to be discussed in comments. Good answer and thanks for the HTML5 reference! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some function names are simply reserved or already used. Another would be "evaluate".

I recommend prepending something to all of your function and variable names to avoid this kinds of situations. Example: "sto_download"

Comment: If I take the function definition out of the script, and `console.log(download)` or `console.log(download())`, then I get `download is not defined`.

Comment: Does not really explain what's going on in Chrome, does it?