# how to save canvas as png image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png, save-image

I have a canvas element with a drawing in it, and I want to create a button that when clicked on, it will save the image as a png file. So it should open up the save, open, close dialog box...

I do it using this code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

But when I test it out in IE9, a new window opens up saying "the web page cannot be displayed"
and the url of it is:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save svg canvas to local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483919/how-to-save-svg-canvas-to-local-filesystem)

Answer (score 88):

try this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("alpha");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var newTab = window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
newTab.document.write("<img src='" + dataURL + "' alt='from canvas'/>");
```

This shows image from canvas on new page, but if you have `open popup in new tab` setting it shows `about:blank` in address bar.

EDIT:- though `window.open("<img src='"+ canvas.toDataURL('image/png') +"'/>")` does not work in FF or Chrome, following works though rendering is somewhat different from what is shown on canvas, I think transparency is the issue:

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
```

Comment: it crashes on this command: var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');

Comment: i changed it to this: var w=window.open('about:blank');, and now the image opens up in a new window, but how do I get it so that its a save close box, i don't want to have to right click the image and hit save as...

Answer (score 38):

[FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) should be able to help you here.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
// draw to canvas...
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    saveAs(blob, "pretty image.png");
});
```

Comment: There is a lot that doesn't work in IE9 :-( Quite a bit can be fixed with polyfills but I am afraid this is beyond that. If you can I suggest using Google Chrome Frame for users using IE.

Comment: @VagueExplanation toBlob() is not supported on Safari. But a simple polyfill can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Answer (score 33):

To accomodate all three points:

- button
- save the image as a png file
- open up the save, open, close dialog box

The file dialog is a setting in the browser.

For the button/save part assign the following function, boiled down from other answers, to your buttons onclick:

```
function DownloadCanvasAsImage(){
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'CanvasAsImage.png');
    let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    let url = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-stream');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('href', url);
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/noontz/pen/XWWVYaw)

Another, somewhat cleaner, approach is using [Canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob):

```
function DownloadCanvasAsImage(){
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'CanvasAsImage.png');
    let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      downloadLink.setAttribute('href', url);
      downloadLink.click();
    });
}
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/noontz/pen/PooOyjO)

Neither solution is 100% cross browser compatible, so check the client

Comment: After SO much time looking for a solution, THIS is the one that worked for me.  On Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit), which is what I'm using.  I should check other browsers but I sure hope that anything up-to-date would still work.

Comment: Nice! Does this also support saving PNG images with an alpha channel? Or would an accompanying mask need to be generated?

Comment: @Mentalist Yes.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle  Just use a fill color with full alpha e.g. ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF00';

Answer (score 28):

I used this solution to set the **file name**:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="downloader" onclick="download()" download="image.png">Download!</a>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
function download(){
    document.getElementById("downloader").download = "image.png";
    document.getElementById("downloader").href = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem and this is the best solution without any external or additional script libraries:
In Javascript tags or file create this function:
We assume here that canvas is your canvas:

```
function download(){
        var download = document.getElementById("download");
        var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png")
                    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        download.setAttribute("href", image);

    }
```

In the body part of your HTML specify the button:

```
<a id="download" download="image.png"><button type="button" onClick="download()">Download</button></a>
```

This is working and download link looks like a button. Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, in IE 11 it clears the screen and changes the url to: 
   data:image/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw

Answer (score 6):

I maybe discovered a better way for not forcing the user to right click and "save image as". Live draw the canvas base64 code into the `href` of the link and modify it so the download will start automatically. I don't know if it's universally browser compatible, but [it should work with the main/new browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('your-canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var C = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

$('#your-canvas').mousedown(function(event) {
    // feel free to choose your event ;) 

    // just for example
    // var OFFSET = $(this).offset();
    // var x = event.pageX - OFFSET.left;
    // var y = event.pageY - OFFSET.top;

    // standard data to url
    var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    // modify the dataUrl so the browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newdata = imgdata.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-stream');
    // give the link the values it needs
    $('a.linkwithnewattr').attr('download','your_pic_name.png').attr('href',newdata);

});
```

You can wrap the `<a>` around anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

Submit a form that contains an input with value of canvas toDataURL('image/png') e.g

//JAVASCRIPT

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var url = canvas.toDataUrl('image/png');
```

Insert the value of the url to your hidden input on form element.

//PHP

```
    $data = $_POST['photo'];
    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    file_put_contents("i".  rand(0, 50).".png", $data);
```

Comment: This works nicely, except the JavaScript function `canvas.toDataUrl(...)` should be `canvas.toDataURL(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('body').after('<a id="Download" target="_blank">Click Here</a>');

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('Download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'test.png');
}, false);

function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.Download = filename;
}
```

You can just put this code in console in firefox or chrom and after changed your canvas tag ID in this above script and run this script in console.

After the execute this code you will see the link as text "click here" at bottom of the html page. click on this link and open the canvas drawing as a PNG image in new window save the image.

Answer (score 0):

**Full Working HTML Code**. Cut+Paste into new .HTML file:

Contains Two Examples:

1. Canvas in HTML file.
2. Canvas dynamically created with Javascript.

Tested In:

1. Chrome
2. Internet Explorer
3. *Edge (title name does not show up)
4. Firefox
5. Opera

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> #SAVE_CANVAS_TEST# </title>
    <meta 
        name   ="author" 
        content="John Mark Isaac Madison"
    >
    <!-- EMAIL: J4M4I5M7 -[ＡＴ]- Hotmail.com -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="about_the_code">
    Illustrates:
    <ol>
    <li>How to save a canvas from HTML page.     </li>
    <li>How to save a dynamically created canvas.</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<canvas id="DOM_CANVAS" 
        width ="300" 
        height="300"
></canvas>

<div id="controls">
    <button type="button" style="width:300px;"
            onclick="obj.SAVE_CANVAS()">
        SAVE_CANVAS ( Dynamically Made Canvas )
    </button>

    <button type="button" style="width:300px;"
            onclick="obj.SAVE_CANVAS('DOM_CANVAS')">
        SAVE_CANVAS ( Canvas In HTML Code )
    </button>
</div>

<script>
var obj = new MyTestCodeClass();
function MyTestCodeClass(){

    //Publically exposed functions:
    this.SAVE_CANVAS = SAVE_CANVAS;

    //:Private:
    var _canvas;
    var _canvas_id = "ID_OF_DYNAMIC_CANVAS";
    var _name_hash_counter = 0;

    //:Create Canvas:
    (function _constructor(){
        var D   = document;
        var CE  = D.createElement.bind(D);
        _canvas = CE("canvas");
        _canvas.width = 300;
        _canvas.height= 300;
        _canvas.id    = _canvas_id;
    })();

    //:Before saving the canvas, fill it so
    //:we can see it. For demonstration of code.
    function _fillCanvas(input_canvas, r,g,b){
        var ctx = input_canvas.getContext("2d");
        var c   = input_canvas;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    }

    //:Saves canvas. If optional_id supplied,
    //:will save canvas off the DOM. If not,
    //:will save the dynamically created canvas.
    function SAVE_CANVAS(optional_id){

        var c = _getCanvas( optional_id );

        //:Debug Code: Color canvas from DOM
        //:green, internal canvas red.
        if( optional_id ){
            _fillCanvas(c,0,255,0);
        }else{
            _fillCanvas(c,255,0,0);
        }

        _saveCanvas( c );
    }

    //:If optional_id supplied, get canvas
    //:from DOM. Else, get internal dynamically
    //:created canvas.
    function _getCanvas( optional_id ){
        var c = null; //:canvas.
        if( typeof optional_id == "string"){
            var id = optional_id;
            var  d = document;
            var c  = d.getElementById( id );
        }else{
            c = _canvas; 
        }
        return c;
    }

    function _saveCanvas( canvas ){
        if(!window){ alert("[WINDOW_IS_NULL]"); }

        //:We want to give the window a unique
        //:name so that we can save multiple times
        //:without having to close previous
        //:windows.
        _name_hash_counter++              ; 
        var NHC = _name_hash_counter      ;
        var URL = 'about:blank'           ;
        var name= 'UNIQUE_WINDOW_ID' + NHC;
        var w=window.open( URL, name )    ;

        if(!w){ alert("[W_IS_NULL]");}

        //:Create the page contents,
        //:THEN set the tile. Order Matters.
        var DW = ""                        ;
        DW += "<img src='"                 ;
        DW += canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        DW += "' alt='from canvas'/>"      ;
        w.document.write(DW)               ;
        w.document.title = "NHC"+NHC       ;

    }

}//:end class

</script>

</body>
<!-- In IE: Script cannot be outside of body.  -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Tovask's answer but it doesn't work due to the function having the name `download` ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852336/7219748) explains why). I also don't see the point in replacing "data:image/..." with "data:application/...".

The following code has been tested in Chrome and Firefox and seems to work fine in both.

JavaScript:

```
function prepDownload(a, canvas, name) {
    a.download = name
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL()
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="prepDownload(this, document.getElementById('canvasId'), 'imgName.png')">Download</a>
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution via `vue` and async support

```
async downloadImage () {
  const canvas = this.$refs.canvas
  const blob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve))

  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a')
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  downloadLink.download = 'mycanvasimage.png'
  downloadLink.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner should do it:

```
function downloadCanvasAsImage(canvas)
{
    // open canvas as image in new window
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), '_blank'));
}
```

Pass the canvas by Javascript or with Jquery like `var canvas = $('canvas')[0];`

This solution is compliant with Content-Security-Policy.

[Credits SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75453190/1066234)

Comment: To improve this answer: please indicate which part of this 'one-liner' saves the image of the canvas as a PNG... ? it seems mostly to put the canvas in a new window

Answer (score -1):

```
var canvasId = chart.id + '-canvas';
var canvasDownloadId = chart.id + '-download-canvas';
var canvasHtml = Ext.String.format('<canvas id="{0}" width="{1}" height="{2}"></canvas><a id="{3}"/>',
canvasId,
chart.getWidth(),
chart.getHeight(),
canvasDownloadId);
var canvasElement = reportBuilder.add({ html: canvasHtml });

var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);

var canvasDownload = document.getElementById(canvasDownloadId);
canvasDownload.href = chart.getImage().data;
canvasDownload.download = 'chart';

canvasDownload.click();
```