# Missing extension when saving image from canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, base64, todataurl

I use this code to save images in Javascript :

```
window.location.href = grid.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

The code works, but the file saved doesn't have any extension, I have to rename it manually.

My question is how can I put the extension at the end ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toDataURL` produces a data-uri not a file name so extensions doesn't apply in this case.

A data-uri is simply a text encoded version of the binary content which some browsers can read as a file - a data-stream if you will. As data streams doesn't have any filename you can't attach one.

You can work around this by setting an anchor tag like this:

```
<a id="imageLink" href="data-uri-here" download="myFilename.png">
    Click to download
</a>
```

In JavaScript you can set these attributes dynamic:

```
imageLink.href = grid.toDataURL();
imageLink.download = 'myOtherFilename.png';
```

Comment: Very cool stuff ! Thank you ;) Is there an other way to produce this instead of declare <a> link in html ? I use dat-gui library for my buttons and I don't know how to create the download attr.

Comment: @mickaelb91 sure, you can simply create the tag in javascript as well. There is also the option of automagically trigger a click as well. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480474/how-to-save-an-image-from-canvas/18480879#18480879