# How to save the signature to local drive

Tags: javascript, html, savefiledialog

I have used the below code to get the signature and I would like to save the signature to local drive when click the button. Kindly guide me how to implement from the below code.

**Code Source:** https://codeload.github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad/legacy.zip/master

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Require a Drawn Signature · Signature Pad</title>
  <style>
    body { font: normal 100.01%/1.375 "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
  </style>
  <link href="../assets/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function signatureSave() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="" class="sigPad">
    <label for="name">Print your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
    <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
    <ul class="sigNav">
      <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" >Draw It</a></li>
      <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sig sigWrapper">
      <div class="typed"></div>
      <canvas class="pad" width="198" id="newSignature" height="55"></canvas>
      <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
    </div>
<button type="button" onClick="signatureSave()">Save signature</button>

<img id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png"/>
  </form>

  <script src="../jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
    });
  </script>
  <script src="../assets/json2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: use `localStorage.setItem("key_name", key_value)` and `localStorage.getItem("key_name")` . Read more about `localStorage`.

Comment: @Aroll605 In where i have to use above code.

Comment: I believe he wants to output the canvas to an actual image on the client computer. With JavaScript alone, I do not think that is possible. What you could do is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server, but return a physical file URL to the client with the AJAX response so that they can save it.

Comment: Not the client computer. I will run this in offline so it should stored the image to local drive via save dialog box.

Comment: See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480879) here

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.setItem("signature", dataURL);

var signature = localStorage.getItem("signature");
```

Comment: Am not able open the save dialog box.

Comment: This is just a tool for saving some data locally. You still have to program it to make it look like it's saving something.