# Save Canvas With A Custom File Name

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following code to save what is on the canvas to a file, but when it saves it saves as `download` as the file name. What can I do to use a custom filename instead of `download`?

```
// Get the Canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// Handle Saving the Canvas
$(document).on("click", "#save-graph", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    window.location.href = image;
});
```

Comment: Save to server and push URL with images save in Server :3

Comment: I was thinking of sending it to php and decoding the base64 and forcing a download from there... but I was hoping for a JS solution if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow this:  http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

[how to save canvas as png image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image)

Comment: That will do just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link for that purporse with the atribute download like this:

```
<a id="save-graph" href="" download="custom_name.png">
```

And on clicking that link everything will stay the same, just change href attribute of the link and trigger click:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save-graph", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    $("#save-graph").attr("href", image);
    $('#save-graph')[0].click();
});
```