# Save HTML element locally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

My [Snippet](https://snippet.christopherkade.com/) tool allows users to save/copy code snippets in order to share them. I use `html2canvas` in order to display the snippet that the user has created in the console and allow them to save it.

But I have found many problems in their display on browsers other than Firefox,  as you can see [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15229355/32991543-6ecd0bfe-cd35-11e7-97e4-8449d8808296.png) (it's blurry and the letter spacing is abnormal).

Here's how I save the snippet once the user presses "Save":

```
// Call html2canvas with the console element
html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName('console'), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var url = canvas.toDataURL()

    // Set the element's URL in an img tag
    var img = '<img src="' + url + '" style="border:0;"></img>'

    // Open a window and display the image in it
    var x = window.open();
    x.document.open();
    x.document.write(img);
    x.document.close();
  }
});
```

My best solution at the moment is to have the snippet saved locally and directly to the user, how may I have a specific HTML element downloaded using Javascript?

EDIT:

This is the HTML element that I wish to save, it contains the console design and a `codemirror` component that represents the text editor in which users type:

```
<div class="console">
  <div class="console-header">
    <div class="console-buttons">
      <div class="console-button button-1"></div>
      <div class="console-button button-2"></div>
      <div class="console-button button-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="console-content">
    <codemirror [(ngModel)]="content" [config]="config"></codemirror>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image

Comment: Not really, I only have a canvas element when I use `html2canvas`, I'm asking for new ways to save the console HTML element locally.

Comment: what is your `console` element? Can you provide some HTML to clarify?

Comment: Absolutely, I have added the element in question. As you can see I save said element with `html2canvas`, but its display is abnormal on certain browsers, so I'm looking for another way of saving it locally.

Comment: In your question you state "But I have found many problems in their display on browsers other than Firefox." Does that mean that html2canvas failing to render correctly? Or do you need a new way to save a canvas to the file system?

Comment: I'm confused. Is the goal to save the code snippet, or to save a picture of the code snippet?  If it's the code itself, why the roundtrip through canvas: wouldn't it be easier and more useful to just store the text and present it as entered?

Comment: html2canvas does fail to render correctly therefore I'm looking for a new way to save the canvas to the file system.

The goal is to save a picture of the code snippet, that's why the text editor, canvas and html2canvas are necessary.