# html2canvas problem: Background Image(external) missing।

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image, html2canvas

I can not download as "jpg/png/pdf" with a background image, just downloading the text. Using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
        var getCanvas; // global variable

        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
            }
        });

        $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function() {
            var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
            $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href",
                newData);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This element "#btn-Convert-Html2Image" should support "href" attribute and be `<a>` 
You could wrap you button to `<a>`
for example
Looks to this example [how to save canvas as png image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image)