# Is there a way to export a 3D model to a PNG image with Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I want to make a webpage for a 3D vehicle model with Three.js where you can choose the perspective from where you can look at it. After you should be able to download a PNG image of this vehicle from that perspective with a transparent background.

The Three.js part is no problem. But downloading the image is an issue

Answer (score 2):

three.js is a library of webgl which draw in `<canvas>`.

`<canvas>` can sava as image whenever you want.

set three.js WebGLRenderer preserveDrawingBuffer as true:

`const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true,preserveDrawingBuffer: true });`

save canvas as image:

```html
<button id="save"> save image</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById('save').onclick=()=>{
  saveImage()
}

function saveImage() {
  const canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]
  const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = image.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
  a.download="image.png"
  a.click();
}
```

codepen link :https://codepen.io/alwxkxk/pen/JjPMyNW

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `canvas` element in which Three.js renders the 3D scene, and use it to create a download of its content. [There is already a Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image) concerning this issue.