# how to download image in javascript which is based on chart js

Tags: javascript

I have an array with different symbols and I am looping over that array to get each symbol but after getting that symbol I am calling an API which is creating a chart in chart js. Now What I want is to download that chart in the form of an image or png.
symbols = ['a', 'b','c']

here the chart is creating using chart.js
and the chart is creating inside this canvas

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="715" height="715" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 794.444px; width: 794.444px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: confirm if this is not what you're looking for here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image)

Comment: yes but I tried all these methods and are not working