# onclick download function is an empty string?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am having an odd problem in my onclick handler.

I am calling a javascript function "download" in the onclick of an . This has been in use on production websites for years. Recently, I get a strange javascript error when clicking the button in Firefox or Chrome (not a problem in IE8). Firefox says "TypeError: download is not a function" and Chrome says "TypeError: string is not a function".

HTML:

```
<a onclick="download('position','container','ids');return false;" href="#">Run download</a>
```

JS:

```
function download(position, container, ids) {
  alert('in download');
}
```

You can see this demonstrated in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttD3r/3/).

Primarily, I would like to know WHY this doesn't work (other functions work fine). It looks like if I rename the function or use a button instead of a link, the problem will be solved as well, but deploying such a change will be a nightmare. If it is necessary, that's fine, but I want to know why the download function no longer works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use "download" as a function name in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Thanks for identifying that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that, with HTML5, `<a>` tags support a new attribute named "download" (see [this link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) for example), that has an empty value by default.

Your code will work if you change it to:

```
<a onclick="self.download('position','container','ids');return false;" href="#">Run download</a>
```

Indeed, events (onclick in this case) run in the scope of the element they are bound to (`<a>` here), so "download" means this.download if it exists.