# Is "remove" a reserved keyword in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reserved-words

I have an interesting problem, and I think I got to the root of it, but I wanted to be sure.  I have a link that calls a function called remove().  All browsers except Chrome had no issues with the function.  However, the link that is clicked disappeared in Chrome, even when I simplified the function as in the example below.  I have seen this question: [Can't use "download" as a function name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript). In the links, however, I did not see anything about "remove" as a reserved keyword.  My question is this, I am correct about this being a keyword?  If so, is there anywhere I can find a list of Google keywords?  I have searched and have not found this to be a problem anywhere else.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove()">Remove</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function remove(){
 alert("Hi");
}
```

Comment: I'm able to use it from the console

Comment: yes, also words like `status`

Comment: I think you're right - take a look at: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/y9huP7JttMY

Comment: try `status = {}` will give a string value `"[object Object]"`

Comment: You can see that `remove` is a member of anchor elements in Chrome: `var anch = document.createElement("a"); console.log(anch.remove);`

Comment: Thanks guys, that is quite helpful. @Adrift, that link does help, I was going to mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I undeleted my answer - mark whoever's helped the most :)

Comment: @Arun, thanks, I will try that if I happen to run into something like that again.

Comment: @apsillers where can I see that?  I am not very familiar with Chrome.

Comment: @illinoistim [Pull up the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) with `Ctrl+Shift+J`. You can type in code there and see the output from calls to `console.log`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elements in Chrome have a `.remove()` method which allows for self-removal of an element instead of having to do it from the parent.

The trouble is that when using attribute handlers, you get a different scope chain. That scope chain includes the element itself, as well as the `document`. This means that all properties of the element and `document` show up as variables.

Because you named your function `remove()`, and because it's a global function/variable, it is being shadowed by the `.remove` property *(now variable)* on the element itself. This can be seen with an alert. If you change your handler to:

```
onclick="alert(remove)"
```

...you'll get something like:

```
function remove() { [native code] }
```

So it's not that it's reserved, but rather that it's used as a property which ends up shadowing the global.

---

To fix it, either use the global directly:

```
onclick="window.remove()"
```

Or change the function name.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  I will just change the function name.

Comment: Just wanted to note `.remove()` is not just a property chrome elements have - it's a part of the new spec :)

Answer (score 1):

I had no issue in chromium using it, well not in this manner

```
<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>

function remove() {
    alert("Hi");
}

document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", remove, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FA8M4/)

Inline javascript is considered bad practice.

If you have more elements using the same function, just add more lines, like this

```
document.getElementById("remove1").addEventListener("click", remove, false);
document.getElementById("remove2").addEventListener("click", remove, false);
document.getElementById("remove3").addEventListener("click", remove, false);
document.getElementById("remove4").addEventListener("click", remove, false);
```

or you could get a nodelist and loop through that

```
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=remove]");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodelist, function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", remove, false);
}
```

You can take a look at another [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) to find out more about the differences between event binding methods, also do a little G searching on the subject will give you further information. And of course, you would have avoided the issue that you were experiencing by doing it in this manner.

Comment: Can you explain more on why it is better to use the addEventListener?  What should I do if there is more than one reference to the remove function?

Comment: Hopefully that's enough information to answer your further question, but I see you have already chosen an answer that you were happy with.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation on it, but DOM  elements in Chrome have a native method `remove` that apparently removes them.  In `onclick`, `this` actually refers to the element itself so it ends up calling `this.remove()` which removes the element.  To get around this, you can just call `window.remove()` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/3YkZH/1/

It would also be better to use standard event binding via `addEventListener` which does not have this problem when simply calling `remove`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3YkZH/2/

Comment: It's a part of the DOM specification :) http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-remove fairly new too.