# Remove localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I have a textfield, a button for adding the text to localstorage and a button to remove it.

This is my script:

```
function save() {
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    localStorage.setItem('text', fieldValue);
}


function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
    if(storedValue) {
        document.getElementById('textfield').value = storedValue;
    }
}


function remove() {

    document.getElementById('textfield').value = '';
    localStorage.removeItem('text');

}
```

The save and load functions both work, but when I click the "remove button", it removes the button itself instead of the local storage value.

Comment: That sounds wacky... code seem fine. could you set up a fiddle and include the html you're using?

Comment: Agreed with @KenFyrstenberg -- I call shenanigans unless I see a fiddle!

Comment: fiddle or it didn't happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove()` seems to be a reserved function name in Javascript. If you call it using `onclick` for example, it will just remove the element rather than call the defined function.

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mW644/

If you inspect the function using `<button onclick="alert(remove)">Test</button>` you get a native function instead of the one you defined:

```
function remove() {
    [native code]
}
```

Rename `remove()` to something else and it will work fine.

Comment: `.remove()` is a jQuery method to remove the element from the DOM, so it may be a consequence of him having jQuery loaded (although he doesn't say if he included it or not so I'm not certain).

Comment: My fiddle does not have jQuery loaded and it still happens. It's actually a native function.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151295/is-remove-a-reserved-keyword-in-google-chrome