# Why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: download is not a function"

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="#" onClick="download();">download</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function download() {
    alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

When I click the link, I don't see an alert. Instead it says the function doesn't exist. Why?

When I rename download to downloadx, it still doesn't work, so it's not the name of my function that's a problem.

Comment: The function should be defined before you bind it. Add the `<a>` below the script tag.

Comment: HTML files are sequential.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work on JS Fiddle either, where the javascript function is defined before the HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/desbest/8f6r0e2e/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use "download" as a function name in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate @gmo because when I rename the `download` function to `downloadx` it still doesn't work.

Comment: @desbest I just did exactly that, and `downloadx` works fine for me.

Comment: no?... It does work for me with no problem at all when I rename the function.. can you add a `snippet code` here to test it please?

Comment: You need to select `No wrap -In body` in JSFiddle under Frameworks & Extensions. http://jsfiddle.net/8f6r0e2e/6/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/8f6r0e2e/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as @gmo said your code will never work outside JSFiddle because of the name of the function.

Read More about it [HERE (Can't use “download” as a function name in javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript)

**From now on i'll use `downloadx` as the function's name**

Instead another problem caused by JSFiddle makes your code non functioning even if you use `downloadx`.
[simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

JSfiddle wrap your code inside a `window.onload` function, so the `download` function is outside of the scope.

```
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function downloadx() {
    alert("hello");
}
}//]]>
```

#### SOLUTION 1 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f6r0e2e/9/)

you should declare it directly on window

```
window.downloadx = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

#### SOLUTION 2 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f6r0e2e/8/)

```
Select No wrap - in <head>
```

On the left column in JSFiddle

#### NB

In any case you should use another name for the function, this is the reason why it doesn't work outside JSFiddle.

Comment: Non of both examples works with the original code from OP, you're using ***downloadx*** as function name and that solve the problem by itself.

Comment: No it doesn't solve the problem of the OP by itself, your downvote is ridicolous as your stubbornness because that's not the only problem of the OP. Here the proof http://jsfiddle.net/8f6r0e2e/10/

Comment: No? Can you try your solution with OP code and see if it's works... And then, use that solution in a real production environment.. About the downvote, it's not about points, it's about this solution in my opinion, do not solve the main problem and therefore do not have to be the accepted answer (neither mine, as I say in my first comment, I consider this question as a duplicate)

Comment: I hope you are satisfied now ;)

Comment: Perfect, that's a full answer and cover all issues. (But it's no need to give the credits to me, it's no my answer) anyway my Downvote it's now an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I still think it's a duplicate question from here: [Can't use "download" as a function name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript)
And related exclusive on the function name in `a` tag.

> *...<a> elements have a download attribute in HTML5 as explained
>   [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-hyperlink-download)...*

Maybe a workaround is possible, but definitely not recommendable to mess with browser native functions.

But.. if you still think that it's not.. please try this:
(no hacks needed)

```js
function download() {
    alert("hello");
}

function downloadx() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="download();">download</a> <-- not working
<br />
<a href="#" onClick="downloadx();">downloadx</a> <-- works
<br />
<span onClick="download();">download</span> <-- works
```

The last one use `download` as `function name` and also work, why?
Because it's not an <a> tag.

Comment: Why can't `download` be used as a function name on the <a> tag?

Comment: Please read the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript (<a> elements have a download attribute in HTML5 as explained here...)